# How to print dwg file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dwg

I want to print a dwg file programmatically in my c# project without opening AutoCad.my application is network base and my file is in a shared folder.I do not know how should i do that?

Comment: Print as in to a printer or a PDF or something?  You might also be interested in this question: [Open source cad drawing (dwg) library in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169390/open-source-cad-drawing-dwg-library-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ROMANARMY, Thanks for your reply,i want to print to a printer in my network.

Comment: please help me... what should i do????

Answer (score 2):

this is abit tricky -
You can use Microsoft's `print` command, im combination with `System.Diagnostics.Process`:

The file extenstion DWG belongs to Autocad - hence when Windows will try to use 'print' with this file,
it will be printed using AutoCad

Try this one:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static void printDWGFile(string f)
{
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "print";
startInfo.Arguments = f;
Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

and call:

```
printDWGFile("c:/Some-Autocad-File.dwg");
```

good luck!

Comment: Doesn't really satisfy the "without opening AutoCAD" part of the question.  It might be that he doesn't have AutoCAD installed on the machine that will be doing this (or it could be part of a batch process).

Comment: @Shai,Thanks. i have tried your way but anything happens.just a commandline window open and close again rapidly.

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi what happens if you try to execute this through cmd.exe?
goto Start->Run...->cmd.exe (press enter) 
Assuming the DWG file is called file1.dwg, try running
print file1.dwg
and see what happens

Comment: @Shai,I have tried your solution and i have received this message: "file1.dwg is currently being printed", but nothing happened.what does it mean?

Comment: Can you make sure that .dwf files are associated with AutoCad? (i.e just try to double-click a .dwg file, see if it opens)

Comment: @Shai,yes i am sure. dwg is an extention for autocad files.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a .NET component that can read/render DWG files, have a look at e.g. [CadLib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.htm). the Open Design Alliance also have a C++ component with .NET wrappers: http://opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/teigha_dot_net.